# How to convert raw json to required format in pythonic way

Tags: python, json, mapping

I have json from some service, where each value is different row.

Input example:

```
[
    {'author': 'alf', 'topic': 'topic1', 'lang': 'ge', 'value': 11},
    {'author': 'alf', 'topic': 'topic1', 'lang': 'ge', 'value': 22},
    {'author': 'bob', 'topic': 'topic1', 'lang': 'ge', 'value': 33},
    {'author': 'bob', 'topic': 'topic1', 'lang': 'ge', 'value': 44},
    {'author': 'alf', 'topic': 'topic1', 'lang': 'fr', 'value': 99},
    {'author': 'alf', 'topic': 'topic2', 'lang': 'ge', 'value': -20},
]
```

Output example:

```
{
    'alf': {
        'topic1': [
            {'ge': [11, 22]},
            {'fr': [99]}
        ],
        'topic2': [
            {'ge': [-20]}
        ]
    },
    'bob': {
        'topic1': [
            {'ge': [33, 44]}
        ]
    }
}
```

So basically this is simple transformation via grouping specified keys to collect all values in to one array.

I done this transformation via checking and creating required key if it is missing:

```
for entry in self._raw_data:
  parsed = {}
  author = entry["author"]
  topic = entry["topic"]
  lang = entry["lang"]
  value = entry["value"]
  if not parsed.get(author):
    parsed[author] = {}
  if not parsed[author].get(topic):
    parsed[author][topic] = []
  #etc
```

I am sure, that could be done in more transparent way. Can anyone recommend something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to change the type of `"topic"`'s value from `list` to `dict`, you can use [`.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
res = {}
for entry in raw_data:
    res.setdefault(entry['author'], {}).setdefault(entry["topic"], {}).setdefault(entry["lang"], []).append(entry["value"])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{
    "alf": {
        "topic1": {
            "fr": [99],
            "ge": [11, 22]
        },
        "topic2": {
            "ge": [-20]
        }
    },
    "bob": {
        "topic1": {
            "ge": [33, 44]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that will work, but i sacrifice ```topic``` type. i think this isn't a big problem, thanks